# type script, runtime error while trying to import localForage

Tags: javascript, typescript, localforage

i am getting this error after trying to import "localForge":
 `Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “localforage”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.`

My tsconfig:

```
 
{   "compilerOptions": {   
        "outDir": "./dist/",  
        "sourceMap": true,  
        "strict": false,  
        "noImplicitReturns": true,  
        "noImplicitAny": true,  
        "module": "es6",  
        "moduleResolution": "node",  
        "target": "es5",  
        "allowJs": true,  
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true  
    },  
    "include": [  
        "./src/**/*"  
    ]}
```

import: `import * as localForage from "localforage";`
also i have tried:
`import { default as localForage } from "localforage";`,
`import localForage from "localforage";`

Answer (score 0):

Using node modules in the browser does not work right out of the box.
Have a look at [browserify](https://browserify.org/) for example.